# Gerar erro de compilação em C para o não uso de uma função

Tags: c, preprocessador

Um problema surgiu na criação de uma mini-biblioteca para simular Threads em um PIC.

Precisaria obrigar o programador a implementar uma função. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de usar os pré-processadores dentro de funções e só chama-lo se a função for utilizada.

Seria algo parecido com isso:

```
void teste(){
    #define _teste
}

int main(){
    teste();

    return 0;
 } 

 #ifndef _teste
     #error "Chame a funcao teste()"
 #endif
```

É possível fazer isso de alguma maneira?

Edit: Como retornar um erro informativo, em C, na hora da compilação pela falta de algo necessário para o funcionamento, como inicialização de um timer por exemplo, que não gera erro de compilação?

Comment: Não sei se entendi ao certo o seu problema, mas parece ser um exemplo de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). A finalidade do pré-processador não é essa. Se o programador deveria implementar uma função declarada em algum lugar e ele não o fizer, o resultado é um erro de compilação, o que já sinalizaria ao programador que há algo muito errado.

Comment: A ideia é so permitir executar o código para baixo apenas se uma função tiver sido chamada ? Se for o caso é claramente um problema XY

Comment: Certo, mas gostaria de um erro mais informativo para que ficasse mais fácil a utilzação da biblioteca. Vou dar uma olhada no link. E a função não gera um erro de compilação, apenas bagunça o código pois é o setup de uma interrupção.

Comment: Certo, acredito ser um problema XY kkk. Então vou tentar ser mais específico ... Como retornar um erro informativo em C na hora da compilação pela falta de algo necessário para o funcionamento que não gera erro de compilação?

Comment: Acho que a minha resposta abaixo deve satisfazê-lo. Me diga o que acha dela.

Comment: Sim. É o que eu precisava saber. Na verdade então quer dizer que não posso intercalar as duas linguagens de forma que hajam condicionais em uma para executar a outra. Vou tentar implementar a sua ideia do erro com o código e ver se consigo algo relevante.

Answer (score 1):

Um compilador C típico tem essas etapas, exatamente nessa ordem:

- Pré-processamento.
- Análise léxica, sintática e semântica do código.
- Geração de código intermediário (código objeto, esses arquivos com extensão `.o`).
- Linkagem.
- Geração de código executável.

Vamos supor que você comece com isso no `main.c`:

```
void teste();

int main() {
    teste();
}
```

Observe o protótipo da função `teste()` lá. Ela declara que a função existe em algum lugar, e que é responsabilidade do linkador encontrá-la. Se ele não encontrar, lançará um erro assim (supondo que você esteja usando o GCC, mas será algo parecido com algum outro compilador):

```
/home/blablabla/blablabla.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `teste'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A mensagem de erro diz que a função `teste` não foi encontrada. Ela poderia estar declarada em um arquivo diferente (`teste.c` por exemplo):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void teste() {
    printf("foo");
}
```

E então, ao compilar os dois fontes juntos, o linkador irá encontrar a função `teste()`.

Você pode tentar fazer com que o pré-processador trabalhe com isso ao fazer o `main` ser assim:

```
void teste();

int main() {
    teste();
}

#ifndef _teste
#   error Voce esqueceu de implementar o teste.
#endif
```

Se o programador não definir `_teste` em lugar nenhum, esse erro vai aparecer. No entanto, essa solução é incompleta, pois não há garantia de que a função `teste()` e o símbolo `_teste` apareçam juntos. Por exemplo, a verificação é contornada se no `teste.c` houver isso:

```
#define _teste
// Esqueci de implementar a função aqui!
```

Outro que dá errado é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void teste() {
   printf("Foo");
}
// Esqueci de dar o #define _teste
```

Nesse daí, o erro persiste mesmo que a função tenha sido implementada.

No entanto, isso não funciona de forma nenhuma. O pré-processador processa os arquivos separadamente, então mesmo que o programador coloque a função `teste()` e o símbolo `_teste` em outro arquivo, ainda assim o erro será disparado.

Você pode tentar remediar com um `#include` no `main.c`:

```
#include "teste.inc"
void teste();

int main() {
    teste();
}

#ifndef _teste
#   error Voce esqueceu de implementar o teste.
#endif
```

E então, o programador define a função `teste()` e o símbolo `_teste` dentro do `teste.inc`. No entanto, isso não é boa prática de programação porque arquivos de cabeçalho (arquivos com extensão `.h`) não deveriam ter implementação. Se bem que nesse caso, você não está usando o arquivo de cabeçalho exatamente como cabeçalho e sim abusando da definição de cabeçalho para importar uma implementação (logo usamos uma extensão diferente, `.inc`).

O problema é que o pré-processador é apenas uma ferramenta para copiar-e-colar texto e na verdade, é uma linguagem totalmente apartada do C. Existe uma linguagem que é a do pré-processador e outra completamente diferente que é a do compilador e ambas não se comunicam a não ser pelo fato de a saída de uma ser a entrada da outra. Assim sendo, não é possível somente no pré-processador saber se a função foi declarada, pois o pré-processador nem mesmo sabe o que é uma função e ele vê o código dela apenas como um monte de texto a ser cegamente copiado para a saída. Por outro lado, o linkador (que também é separado do compilador e do pré-processador exceto pelo fato dele usar como entrada a saída do compilador) não tem nada que permite mensagens de erro customizadas.

Podemos pensar em uma abordagem diferente. Você pode já providenciar um esqueleto para a função `teste` e abandonar o `#ifdef`. Por exemplo, se for tudo feito em um único código-fonte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void teste();

int main() {
    teste();
}

void teste() {
#   error Voce esqueceu de implementar o teste. Substitua essa mensagem pelo codigo.
}
```

Em múltiplos código-fonte, com a ressalva que você está abusando da finalidade do `#include`, você pode fazer isso no `main.c`:

```
#include "teste.inc"

void teste();

int main() {
    teste();
}
```

E no `teste.inc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void teste() {
#   error Voce esqueceu de implementar o teste. Substitua essa mensagem pelo codigo.
}
```